# JSRR won't go to outside program in LC3

Tags: assembly, lc3

I seem to be having a problem with LC3 assembly.

I'm trying to jump to a subroutine (in another program, otherwise I'd just use JSR), but instead it just goes through to the next command.

I've tried:

```
    LD R0, Subpgm
    JSRR R0
```

and at the bottom, This line to define Subpgm.

```
    Subpgm .FILL x4000
```

I expected this to jump to PC x4000, but instead the PC is just incremented by the normal 1.

Any help would be super appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example program using the `JSRR` instruction.

```
       .ORIG X3000
       LD R0, Subpgm  ; => R0=X4000
       JSRR R0        ; => R7=X3002 PC=X4000
Done   HALT           ; This is at X3002
Subpgm .FILL X4000    ; Address of the 'external' program
       .BLKW X0FFC    ; Fill up the gap between programs
       RET            ; This is at X4000
       .END
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
When I tried to use LEA, instead of loading x4000, it loaded the address of that label... I'll try moving the subprogram closer, but it's a project for class, and they told us the locations to use.
.FILL doesn't set the address to x4000, it just fills a spot of memory with the contents x4000, so LEA won't work for that. Is there another command I should be using instead of .FILL?
I appreciate the answer, maybe you can help further!

Comment: @NaomiSheehan Since x4000 is the internal encoding of `JSRR R0` any jump towards the label _Subpgm_ (using R0) will result in an endless loop! I think it would be best to post the entire description of your assignment.